# How do I kill locked mythtv frontend

Tags: mythtv

I have a new install of Ubuntu 13.10 with mythtv .27 installed. After configuring mythtv FE I tried to exit.  It would not let me exit.

I tried several times without success.  Because mythtv FE loads full screen I didn't have access to any other means of exiting Ubuntu.

I was forced to reboot the computer.  After the reboot Ubuntu automatically loaded mytyuhtv FE, again in full screen mode.

I tried to exit mythtv FE as before but the command is ignored leaving me with a locked computer.  Basically my only options is to prevent mythtv FE from automatically loading after the reboot.

Until I can accomplish that the computer is basically useless.  Here's where I need help because I don't know how to accomplish that.

Any assistance will be appreciated

Comment: Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/33904/how-to-recover-from-fullscreen-crash

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Mythtv. You were able to configure it! When I enter setup-(larger than) fullscreen-I'm unable to get any farther than language and location and cannot see any buttons to click. Try to close it starts an infinite loop and it starts back up again and becomes harder to close.

What I do is use HTOP to find mythtv and issue a kill 9 command.

$ sudo apt-get install htop

You can use htop from a virtual terminal

ctrl+alt+F3 (any F key from 2-5) Return to your GUI screen with ctrl+alt+F7

I also used

$ sudo apt-get remove --purge mythtv

to dump mythtv from my system. Be sure to manually delete the .mythtv file in your home directory.

I've look in vain for instructions on configuring mythtv. There are plenty of install and use instructions but none address the problem of the loop and overblown screen size.

Yes version 0.27 is out now. I'm resigned that Mythtv won't be near a reality until it gets beyond version 1.0! Between Me-Tv (can't change channels but is a GOOD PVR) and TV Time (GREAT picture, no sound) I don't think Ubuntu or Linux can provide a TV media experience for the average end-user at this time. I'm still trying though. Been watching Ubuntu since 7.04. Just went full time (no dual boot) 2 months ago and miss my PVR (we call it DVR in US).